# Using NgFor instead of HTML

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I'm relatively new to angular, and I know there has got to be a better way than what I'm doing. I'd like to use ngfor to loop through and spit out this info vs typing it all by hand. Any recommendations?

Here's my code:

```
<section class="eighth-section our-work">
    <h2 class="uppercase">Our work</h2>
    <a target="blank" href="">
        <img class="lazy our-work__img"
             src="./assets/images/our-work/kma-logo.png"
             alt="KMA Logo"></a>
    <a target="blank" href="https://fwchiro.com/forms/">
        <img class="lazy our-work__img"
             src="./assets/images/ourwork/DF_FWChiroLogo.png"
             alt="Functional Wellness Chiropractic logo"></a>
    <a target="blank" href="https://www.608motorsports.com/">
        <img class="lazy our-work__img"
             src="./assets/images/ourwork/DF_608logo.png"
             alt="608 Motorsports Logo"></a>
    <a target="blank" href="https://dektex.com/">
        <img class="lazy our-work__img"
             src="./assets/images/ourwork/DF_dektexlogo.png"
             alt="DekTex Logo"></a>
    <a target="blank" href="https://kswconstruction.com/">
        <img class="lazy our-work__img"
             src="./assets/images/ourwork/DF_KSWLogo.png"
             alt="KSW Construction Logo"></a>
    <a target="blank" href="https://bzcustomfinishing.com/">
        <img class="lazy our-work__img"
             src="./assets/images/ourwork/DF_BZlogo.png"
             alt="BZ Custom Finishing Logo"></a>
    <a target="blank" href="https://familyfirstverona.com/">
        <img class="lazy our-work__img"
             src="./assets/images/ourwork/DF_famfirstlogo.png"
             alt="Family First Logo"></a>
    <a target="blank" href="https://hamiltonconcretepro.com/">
        <img class="lazy our-work__img"
             src="./assets/images/ourwork/Hamilton_Logo.png"
             alt="Hamilton Concrete Logo"></a>
</section>
```

Item's I'd like to use for looping are the following tags:
src
href
alt

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your component:

```
public links = [
  {src: 'your_src_1', href: 'your_href_1', alt: 'your alt text 1'},
  {src: 'your_src_2', href: 'your_href_2', alt: 'your alt text 2'},
  {src: 'your_src_3', href: 'your_href_3', alt: 'your alt text 3'},
  {src: 'your_src_4', href: 'your_href_4', alt: 'your alt text 4'},
];
```

in your template:

```
<a *ngFor="let link of links" target="blank" [href]="link.href"><img class="lazy our-work__img" [src]="link.src" [alt]="link.alt"></a>
```

should do the trick

the key is you need a data array somewhere that contains objects of all your parameters.  then you can use ngFor to loop through them and use the dataset results.

Comment: Awesome, this did the trick! I was trying to make it a variable and something with the 'this', I have some more learning to do.  Thanks a bunch derelict!

Answer (score -1):

You could have an object in your JS that binds to the HTML. Here's a sample. You should add all the 7 items in though.

```
$scope.foo = [
    {'href' : '',
     'src': '',
     'alt': ''}
]
```

In your HTML you'd use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to acheive a loop:

```
<section class="eighth-section our-work">
  <h2 class="uppercase">Our Work</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="item in foo">
      <a target="blank" href="item.href"><img class="lazy our-work__img" src="item.src" alt="item.alt"></a>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: OP has tagged Angular, not AngularJS